# How to prove the theorems related to updating variables using pairs in Coq?

Tags: coq

I define the values of variables and expression as follows:

```
Inductive id : Set := 
| Id : nat -> id.    

Theorem eq_id_dec :
  forall id1 id2 : id, {id1 = id2} + {id1 <> id2}.
Proof.
 intros id1 id2.
 destruct id1 as [n1]. destruct id2 as [n2].
 destruct (eq_nat_dec n1 n2) as [Heq | Hneq].
 - (* n1 = n2 *)
   left. rewrite Heq. reflexivity.
 - (* n1 <> n2 *)
   right. intros contra. inversion contra. apply Hneq. apply H0.
Defined.

Definition fvalue := id * nat.

Inductive aexp : Type := 
| ANum : nat -> aexp
| AId : id -> aexp
| APlus : aexp -> aexp -> aexp
| AMinus : aexp -> aexp -> aexp
| AMult : aexp -> aexp -> aexp.
```

Then I define a function to update the value of variables:

```
Fixpoint fvalue_up (st : list fvalue) (e : id) (v : nat) :=
match st with
| nil => nil
| h :: st' =>
  if eq_id_dec (fst h) e then (e, v) :: st'
  else fvalue_up st' e v
end.

Definition fvalue_ids (st : list fvalue) :=
  map fst st.

Definition fvalue_update (st : list fvalue) (e : id) (v : nat) :=
  if beq_nat (count_occ eq_id_dec (fvalue_ids st) e) 0
  then (e, v) :: st
  else fvalue_up st e v.



Fixpoint get_fvalue (st : list fvalue) (e : id) (default : nat) :=
match st with
| nil => default
| h :: st' =>
  if eq_id_dec (fst h) e then snd h
  else get_fvalue st' e default
end.

Fixpoint daeval (st : list fvalue) (e : aexp) {struct e} : nat :=
match e with
| ANum n => n
| AId x => get_fvalue st x 0
| APlus a1 a2 => plus (daeval st a1) (daeval st a2)
| AMinus a1 a2  => minus (daeval st a1) (daeval st a2)
| AMult a1 a2 => mult (daeval st a1) (daeval st a2)
end.
```

Now I want to prove the following theorem which I think it is correct.

```
Theorem fvalue_update_same :
  forall (st : list fvalue) (x : id) (e : aexp) (f : aexp -> aexp),
  fvalue_update (fvalue_update st x (daeval st e)) x (daeval (fvalue_update st x (daeval st e)) (f (AId x))) =
  fvalue_update st x (daeval st (f e)).
```

For example, if the initial variable x = 1, we firstly assign x := x + 1, then we assign x := 2 * x, the final variable x = 4. It is equal to that we assign x := 2 * (x + 1) directly. Can anyone give some advice for this theorem ?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example - you're missing some imports (for notation), `eq_id_dec`, and `daeval`.

Comment: @TejChajed Sorry for my careless, I have already added the 
 definition of `eq_id_dec`  and `daeval`.

Answer (score 0):

Your theorem is almost certainly false, with this definition of `daeval` (which I assume evaluates an expression with a context). The reason is that the function `f` can distinguish between the original expression and `AId x`. I think you just want to get rid of that function in the statement (that is, make it the identity function).

```
Fixpoint fvalue_lookup (st: list fvalue) (e:id) : nat :=
  match st with
  | nil => 0
  | (e', v) :: st' => if eq_id_dec e e' then v else fvalue_lookup st' e
  end.

Fixpoint daeval (st:list fvalue) (e:aexp) : nat :=
  match e with
  | ANum n => n
  | AId i => fvalue_lookup st i
  | APlus e1 e2 => daeval st e1 + daeval st e2
  | AMinus e1 e2 => daeval st e1 - daeval st e2
  | AMult e1 e2 => daeval st e1 - daeval st e2
  end.

Definition fvalue_update_same_statement st x e f :=
  fvalue_update (fvalue_update st x (daeval st e)) x (daeval (fvalue_update st x (daeval st e)) (f (AId x))) =
  fvalue_update st x (daeval st (f e)).

Example fvalue_update_same_contradiction :
  ~fvalue_update_same_statement
   [(Id 0, 0)]
   (Id 0)
   (ANum 0)
   (fun e => match e with
          | AId _ => ANum 0
          | ANum _ => ANum 1
          | _ => ANum 4
          end).
Proof.
  compute.
  (* [(Id 0, 0)] = [(Id 0, 1)] -> False *)
  congruence.
Qed.
```

Comment: Yes, I just want to prove that if the _x_ is firstly assigned to _e_, and the _x_ is assigned to _f(x)_, where _f_ is a function for _x_, the result of the operator should equal to that the _x_ is assigned to _f(e)_. `x := e; x := f(x)` is equal to `x := f(e)`.